# What code is this? /^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/

Tags: javascript, regex

So I am extremely new to the Javascript world. I was practicing on codewars having to analyze a pin to make sure it only contained numbers and was either 4 or 6 characters. I looked at the most clever code and the answer was:

```
function validatePIN(pin) {
  return /^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test(pin)
}
```

I've never seen the "/^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/" bit before. Could anyone tell me what this is called so I can research it on my own, or give me a breakdown of how it works?

Comment: Regular expression(regex) validation in javascript...

Comment: [MDN: `RegExp.prototype.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: @sysk The intent of the original is clearer (though indeed equivalent). And "efficiency" in this context is silly-- even if the parens made a difference, you're not matching gigabytes of PINs.

Comment: @alexis but the useless parens are confusing, inducing to ask 'why are the there ... what is the trick'

Comment: Trick? They are there to ensure that `^` and `$` apply to each of the alternatives (since `/^\d{4}|\d{6}$/` matches `^\d{4}` or `\d{6}$`). But never mind, "clear" is really a matter of taste in this case...

Comment: @syck It would be easy to assume so, but [check it](https://regex101.com/r/pT0qP8/1) to see [extra parens](https://regex101.com/r/pT0qP8/2) are needed. But yes, it would me more efficient "at the cost of readability" (ie. not as expressive) but reading RegExps is the same one way or the other

Comment: @syck @CSᵠ Can be pretty easily fixed: `^\d{4}(\d{2})?$` But yea, IMO the only real way to make RegExp "readable" is to add good comments.

Comment: explanation: the error is that {2}? is a "non-greedy" matcher like `x*?` or `x+?`

Comment: Yep, sorry@all, removed my comment because it was misleading and I was in a hurry, so did not check thoroughly what I was typing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), similar to using `return new RegExp('^(\\d{4}|\\d{6})$').test(pin)`  The "literal" part implies that it's a means of representing a specific data type as a string in code—just like `true` and `'true'` are different, as one is a boolean literal and the other is a string literal.

Specifically, the regex `^(\d{4}|\d{6})$` breaks down to:

```
^       a string that starts with...
(       either
  \d    a digit (0-9)...
  {4}   that repeats four times...
|       or
  \d    a digit (0-9)...
  {6}   that repeats six times...
)
$       and then ends
```

So: `'1234'`, `'123456'`, etc would match. `'123.00'`, `'12345'`,`'abc123'`,`'  1234'`, `' 1234 '` would not match.

As noted by several others in the comments on [Draco18s' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34389072/60724) there are several nuances to be aware of with using regex literals in JS:

- The literal syntax doesn't require you to escape special characters within the regex pattern.  Using the RegExp constructor requires you to represent the pattern as a string, which in turn requires escaping.  Note the differences of the `\`'s between the two syntaxes.
- Using a regex literal will treat the regex as a constant, whereas using `new RegExp()` leaves life cycle management of the regex instance up to you.

  > The literal notation is compiled and implies a constant regex, whereas the constructor version is reparsed from the string, and so the literal is better optimized/cached. [jsperf.com/regexp-literal-vs-constructor/4](http://jsperf.com/regexp-literal-vs-constructor/4) Note: you can get basically the same effect by caching the new Regex in a variable, but the literal one is cached at the JIT step – [user120242](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120242/user120242)

  In other words, using a regex literal can avoid potential performance pitfalls:

  **Example:**

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    // Instantiates 1x Regex per iteration
    var constructed = new RegExp('^(\\d{4}|\\d{6})$') 

    // Instantiates 1 Regex
    var literal = /^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/ 
  }
  ```

Comment: Vunderbar. I think this answer in fact covers *everything* brought up about this question and in more detail.

Answer (score 27):

It's a regular expression.

I tend to use http://www.regexpal.com/ when I want to try and find the expression I need, there's also http://regexr.com/ for learning about them (among other resources).

Comment: it's a regex *literal*; more specifically.  The leading and trailing `/`'s aren't part of the regex, but tell Javascript to treat everything between them as one.  It's shorthand for `new Regex('^(\d{4}|\d{6})$')`

Comment: @STW: Your shorthand doesn't work due to lack of escaping. You need `\\d{4}`, since ``\`` needs to be escaped in string literal.

Comment: @STW ... and that's why you should prefer the short syntax if you can use it. It's the right way, not a shorthand.

Comment: As others have noted: it is not a simple shorthand for the Regex constructor.  The literal notation is compiled and implies a constant Regex, whereas the constructor version is reparsed from the string, and so the literal is better optimized/cached.  http://jsperf.com/regexp-literal-vs-constructor/4  Note: you can get basically the same effect by caching the new Regex in a variable, but the literal one is cached at the JIT step

Comment: To all: why does such a question receive so many upvotes? The tiniest amount of research would have answered this effortlessly, IMHO. No offense toward answers. Do you all think so as well?

Comment: @cad I think it is because if you can't recognize it by sight there's no harm in asking "what is this?"  But I am not sure, I didn't upvote the question.

Comment: @edc65 Absolutely spoken, of course not. But for such a question, six upvotes **are** many.

Comment: @cad you must have seen it before I edited it. I frequently hit ' and [enter] at the same time. edc65, I agree that 6 (7 now) is a lot for a question like this. This is also my highest ranked answer and has very nearly put me at the daily rep limit and its only 10am here. My next highest ranked question deals with explaining why `-5 < -3 < -1` evaluates to `0` (due to the implicit conversion of booleans to integers in Matlab). Every question I've ever answered that has had more substance has only ever received one or two upvotes. A few haven't even been accepted (I have the badge for that too)

Comment: RegEx is by nature difficult for many people (especially beginners).  There are also very likely many beginners who are looking up this information on Google at any moment (maybe even how to test for digits).  I even work with people with 10+years programming experience who still can't (/won't) grok RegEx.  Also, this is easy to understand for probably many mods and easy to vote on..

Comment: @Draco18s that is easy to explain.  Those more complex questions are probably more niche (less search hits), and the few mods it was given to probably didn't feel comfortable voting on it.  Basically: it didn't quickly reach the most common denominator

Comment: @user120242 Good point :)  Its not like I care a whole lot (what is rep? just a number), it was just interesting.

Comment: @cad it isn't the best question, but it's about a peculiar JS feature, and is a question everyone asks when they first find a pile of Regex as they stroll through code.  It's also kind of quirky that a `/` is used as a control character for something other than a comment.

Answer (score 15):

Good reference for Javascript RegExp
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

```
^ beginning of line
\d = all digits
{4} = repetition 4 times
| = "or"
$ end of line
```

your example tests for a 4 digit string or 6 digit string